# Reverting data type from string/JSON

Tags: ros, ros2, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had to convert msg like geometry_msg data type to string so that I can upload it to the MYSQL database. I was wondering if there is a way that can revert String back to the original data type. Instead of me trying to use split and other stuff.

[MODIFIED]
After trying to convert to string and store it in the MYSQL database it was generating issues to revert it back, so instead of converting it to string, I had to use JSON format to save it to the database.

creating the table in with json format data type `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_data (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, room_name VARCHAR(255), data JSON)"`

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398574/reverting-data-type-from-string/json/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've converted the msg to string using a yaml format, you could read it back into a message type by first loading it into a dictionary using `yaml.safe_load`, and then filling a message object using `rosidl_runtime_py.set_message_fields`.

Here's an example of a geometry_msgs.msg.Pose being converted to string, and then restored back into a new object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import yaml
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
from rosidl_runtime_py import message_to_yaml, set_message_fields

# Create Pose msg
original = Pose()
original.position.x = 1.0
original.position.y = 2.0
original.position.z = 3.0

# Convert to string
pose_string = message_to_yaml(original)
print("Pose is: \n", pose_string)

# Convert back to yaml
values_dictionary = yaml.safe_load(pose_string)
restored = Pose()
set_message_fields(restored, values_dictionary)

print("Restored x, y, z: ", restored.position.x, restored.position.y, restored.position.z)
```

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-04-06**:
@ijnek tried the method you mentioned. Restoring values doesn't work when data is stored in Pose_string format. So I used `JSON` datatype on the database. It needs a little more modifications to accommodate that.

after converting it to YAML using message_to_yaml

```
data_string = yaml.safe_load(data)
data_string = json.dumps(data_string, indent=4))
```

And it needs to `import json` and to convert back to ROS message is same as you mentioned.
Can you please modify your answer with these lines so that I can mark it as correct?

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-04-06**:
I'm a bit confused with your code suggestion. if you're using a json string instead of a yaml string, you should just have to replace `yaml.safe_load` with `json.loads`:

```
import json

# Convert back to yaml
values_dictionary = json.loads(pose_string)
restored = Pose()
set_message_fields(restored, values_dictionary)
print("Restored x, y, z: ", restored.position.x, restored.position.y, restored.position.z)
```

Any additional settings such as indent would be up to the use case.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-04-07**:
Converting back to `YAML` works both ways using `json.loads` or by `yaml.safe_load` but saving data to the database does not work with only `message_to_yaml` have to use `safe_load` and `json.dumps`

```
# Storing data on database
data = message_to_yaml(data)
data_string = yaml.safe_load(data)
db.create_room(room_name, json.dumps(data_string, indent=4))
```

So your solution works when it just has to convert to string, but not helping with loading on MySQL database. I had followed this [link](https://answers.ros.org/answers/273429/revisions/) for converting it to `JSON`.
Just in case if you want to know the error I am getting when I store using your method
`mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'cleaned_room.data'.`

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-04-07**:
Got it, thanks for the clarification.